# How to fix Flutter Error: FileSystemException: Cannot open file

Tags: android, flutter, git, dart

I am building an app using dart and the dart_git package, which reads data on git repositories, however upon trying to read the git files, I am presented with the following error:
`I/flutter (13909): Error: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/storage/emulated/0/Download/git_repository/.git/config' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)`

Here is my code:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:dart_git/dart_git.dart';
import 'package:dart_git/plumbing/reference.dart';
import 'package:dart_git/git_hash.dart';

import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Git Repository Example')),
        body: Center(
          child: GitRepoSelector(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class GitRepoSelector extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GitRepoSelectorState createState() => _GitRepoSelectorState();
}

class _GitRepoSelectorState extends State<GitRepoSelector> {
  String? _selectedPath;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Text(_selectedPath ?? 'No folder selected'),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            // Request storage permissions
            PermissionStatus status = await Permission.storage.request();
            if (status.isGranted) {
              String? directoryPath =
                  await FilePicker.platform.getDirectoryPath();
              if (directoryPath != null) {
                setState(() {
                  _selectedPath = directoryPath;
                });
                await _initializeGitRepo(Directory(directoryPath));
              }
            } else {
              print('Error: Storage permission not granted');
            }
          },
          child: Text('Select a folder'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Future<void> _initializeGitRepo(Directory directory) async {
    try {
      // Initialize the Git repository
      GitRepository gitRepo = await GitRepository.load(directory.path);

      // Request permission to access the .git/config file
      bool hasPermission = await _hasFileAccessPermission(gitRepo);
      if (!hasPermission) {
        await _requestFileAccessPermission();
        hasPermission = await _hasFileAccessPermission(gitRepo);
        if (!hasPermission) {
          print('Error: Permission denied for file access');
          return;
        }
      }

      // Read the HEAD reference
      Reference? headRef = await gitRepo.head();
      if (headRef != null) {
        // Obtain the object's hash
        GitHash objectId = headRef.target as GitHash;

        // Get the commit author
        final authorResult = await Process.run(
            'git', ['log', '-1', '--pretty=format:%an', objectId.toString()],
            workingDirectory: directory.path);
        final author = authorResult.stdout.trim();

        // Get the commit message
        final messageResult = await Process.run(
            'git', ['log', '-1', '--pretty=format:%s', objectId.toString()],
            workingDirectory: directory.path);
        final message = messageResult.stdout.trim();

        print('Commit author: $author');
        print('Commit message: $message');
      } else {
        print('Error: Unable to find HEAD reference');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error: $e');
    }
  }

  Future<bool> _hasFileAccessPermission(GitRepository gitRepo) async {
    try {
      final file = File('${gitRepo.workTree}/.git/config');

      // Request manage external storage permissions
      PermissionStatus status =
          await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request();
      if (status.isGranted) {
        await file.readAsString();
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  Future<void> _requestFileAccessPermission() async {
    Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> permissionStatus = await [
      Permission.storage,
    ].request();

    if (permissionStatus[Permission.storage] != PermissionStatus.granted) {
      print('Error: Permission denied for file access');
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried adding all of the following lines to my AndroidManifest.xml file, with no avail:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<application
     android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

I have also tried using a physical phone and two separate virtual emulators.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask for those permission that you write on your XML document to the user. But you can`t ask for them using Flutter, it has to be done by with Android code. In order to do this, you need to do the next steps:

1. Create a Channel between Android and Flutter.
2. Use that Channel to call an Android function that ask for that permissions.
3. The user has to enable that permissions.

Here is a GIT repo that do this:

https://github.com/igarleni/flutter_manage_external_storage

I hope it helps!